# Need XSLT template to convert docx file table styles to html

Tags: xslt

I am using xslt1.0 to convert docx file to html..i need a xslt template to handle table styles and themes applied in docx files to reproduce it in html..please help me....

Answer (score 0):

Here is one example of Docx2HTML http://openxmlviewer.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=54508 using XSLT (and an [earlier approach](http://openxmldeveloper.org/articles/333.aspx)).